# Polar form of z = 12i

Tags: complex-numbers

I only know a dab about complex numbers so I was reviewing [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx)  for group theory. I don't understand the first paragraph which isn't explained in detail.
Second, how does the sentence marked with the red arrow follow? $\arg{z} = \pi/2$? Is there a picture?
[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Definition

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: Thanks. Why is the principle value $\in (-\pi, \pi]$? Why exclude $-\pi$? How does this explain the red arrow overhead?

Comment: @FrankMuer You exclude the value so it is injective.  It should take a unique value.

Comment: You agree with the last line of the copied text, don't you?

Comment: @FrankMuer, $$\pi\equiv-\pi\pmod {2\pi}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thanks. I forgot $\pi \text{ degrees/radians } = -\pi \text{ degrees/radians }$

Comment: @FrankMuer For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Therfore it can be expressed as $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now to express $\textbf{z}$ in polar for we have $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ for $|z|$=radius, $\theta=arg(z)$. It's a matter of locating a complex number in the plane.

Here $z=12i$. Graphing $\textbf{z}$ we see that $12i$ is on the positive y-axis.

Thus we obtain that $\textbf{arg}$($z$)=$\frac{\pi}{2}$, $|z|=12$. "| |" is read modulus or distance from the origin to the complex value.

Hence, $z=12e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}=12cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+isin(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

$\textbf{By Euler's formula we have $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$}$.

Comment to question mark in paragraph: A negative real number will lie on the negative x-axis giving it's argument the value $\pi$

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand how you got $\arg{z} = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you please add this to your answer?

Comment: yes, the argument is determined by where the complex number is located. z=12i is located on the positive y-axis which has an angle measure of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does. I upvoted

Comment: @Faraad Please stop writing trigonometric functions as $cos\,\,\color{grey}{\text{or}}\,\,sin\ldots$ by typing `cos` or `sin`, instead write them as $\cos\,\,\color{grey}{\text{or}}\,\,\sin\ldots$ by typing `\cos` or `\sin`...

Answer (score 0):

I think the paragraph says the following: if you write your complex number $z = a + bi$ in polar form as $z = |z|e^{it}$, and if you restrict the $t$'s in $(-\pi, \pi]$, then there is one and only one such $t^*$ that you can find so that you can rewrite your $z$ in the polar form above. The angle $t^*$ (in radian) above is called $Arg(z)$.

Back to your $z = 12i$, for $t \in (-\pi, \pi]$, the only value of $t$ is $t = \pi/2$ so $z = 12*e^{i\pi/2}$. So $Arg(12i) = \pi/2$.

Comment: Please, use LaTeX for your answers

Comment: @MatikKen For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).